# AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to add images to a S3 bucket(Private) using AWS SDK in Java.
I have attached an IAM role to my EC2 instance and this role has access to S3 with the help of IAM policy. I am trying to get the access in my program using credentials attached with instance metadata. But I am getting the following error:

> "amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedXML; Request ID: 56ED3906EA67718B;"

I have checked the instance metadata for credentials and they exist. I am not able to figure out the problem. Following is my code:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider(true)).withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
PutObjectRequest putObj = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file);
```

Comment: This error is not about your instance credentials, but about request you make witch is malformed. Are you sure it originates from these two lines? It seems that something else could be throwing it.

Comment: yes, following that I am using      
s3client.putObject(putObj);
to put my object into the bucket directly(I do not have any folders in the bucket)